# Trying to delete .exe file using Path from windows registries and DeleteFile() method

Tags: c++, winapi

So I need to scan windows registries, display them all on the console and then check which of those values has the same name as set in the code

When the program finds the value with the targeted name I need to terminate it process and delete it from hardware using DeleteFile().

So I have done everything got the path to the .exe file destination but when I'm using DeleteFile(); it doesn't delete the file

```
void EndProcess(HANDLE snap, HANDLE &process, PROCESSENTRY32 pe32, TCHAR 
virusName[], TCHAR valuePath[], wofstream &file)
{
    process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
    if (TerminateProcess(process, 1))
    {
        cout << "Virus process is found and successfully terminated!" << 
    endl;
        file << "Virus process is found and successfully terminated!" << 
    endl;
        CloseHandle(process);
        DeleteFile(valuePath);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to terminate Virus process!" << endl;
        file << "Failed to terminate Virus process!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. This is the last piece of the code where I shut down the process and need to delete the file.

Comment: Depending on the OS, deleting a file that if open by some other application may or may not be possible. Generally, there is *no way* to guarantee deletion of a file (unless of course your code is running in kernel space as part of the file system implementation).

Comment: @Klaidelio If you forgot to mention some essential information you can always [edit] your question, than adding up an unnecessary comment.

Comment: @Klaidelio "I shut down the process" - OK, fine. But *other* processes may have the file open.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's kinda hard to explain. First time doing that kind of stuff. So what I have to do is to delete my other .exe file which is created by me and that program just puts the value to the Windows registry and creates a MessageBox. With this program, I need to delete that registry value and use that path to the file destination and delete it.

Comment: `DeleteFile` works fine. If the file isn't being deleted, then presumably when you call `DeleteFile`, `FALSE` is returned. Is it? You don't check. If `FALSE` is returned, what error code does `GetLastError` return? This is how you begin to debug.

Comment: This program suffers from the universal "what if *two* programs do this" problem.  You made an executable file appear from seemingly nowhere, start rooting through the registry, kill processes, delete files.  That's what a virus does.  You must therefore disable your existing anti-malware product.

Comment: @Hans Passant So I used `GetLastError()` and I received `5` as an error. `5` = `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` So how can I fix that?

Comment: @Klaidelio you can't delete what you don't have access to

Comment: @Jesper Juhl, Since `TerminateProcess` is asynchronous, so it's not other processes but the current process hasn't terminate it yet. So the error code is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Just need to wait the process to be really shut down.

Answer (score 1):

[TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) is asynchronous, it initiates termination and returns immediately. That is to say, it is not certain that the process has been terminated. The simple solution is to add a `Sleep()` for delay.

If you need to be sure the process has terminated, call the [WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) function with a handle to the process. And you also need to add the `SYNCHRONIZE` access right when open the process handle:

```
void EndProcess(HANDLE snap, HANDLE &process, PROCESSENTRY32 pe32, TCHAR
    virusName[], TCHAR valuePath[], wofstream &file)
{
    process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE | SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
    if (TerminateProcess(process, 1))
    {
        cout << "Virus process is found and successfully terminated!" <<
            endl;
        file << "Virus process is found and successfully terminated!" <<
            endl;
        WaitForSingleObject(process, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(process);
        DeleteFile(valuePath);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to terminate Virus process!" << endl;
        file << "Failed to terminate Virus process!" << endl;
    }
}
```